# jQuery mobile and Google Analytics - single-page template

Tags: jquery-mobile, asynchronous, google-analytics

I didn't find an answer to my question anywhere and I know nothing about javascript, so I can't figure it out myself.

If I have jQuery mobile website built so that **every single page is in separate html file** ([single page template](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html)). May I use standard asynchronous Google Analytics code with it, or do I have to make modifications similar to [those used in multi page template](http://blog.mojotech.com/post/29501319906/google-analytics-within-jquery-mobile)?

Would be very thankful if someone could answer this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the standard Google Analytics code. You will however, need to "push" certain page views to Google Analytics because of the way jQuery Mobile handles page navigation.

For example, if you have a Contact form on your site at `contact.html` that, once submitted, goes to a `process.php` page, and then after completing, the user arrives at `thank-you.html`, you will need to call some JavaScript to "push" the pageview to Google Analytics.

For example, if your jQuery Mobile page element (`data-role="page"`) has `id="thank-you"`, then I'd use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).delegate('#thank-you', 'pageshow', function () {
    //Your code for each thank you page load here
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/thank-you.html']);

});
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

I would put this in your `script.js` file which is included in the head after you load jQuery and jQuery Mobile. This fires on each `data-role="page"` `pageshow` event, and is currently working on my live projects just fine.

```
$('[data-role=page]').live('pageshow', function (event, ui) {
    try {
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);

        hash = location.hash;

        if (hash) {
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', hash.substr(1)]);
        } else {
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
        }

    } catch(err) {

    }

});
```

Comment: In my question I should ask about additions not modifications. So it seems to be similar to the way they handle it with multi page template. Do I have to have add id for every page or could I just add some general code that I would include? I don't even use ids pages. Such a code should be placed right before the closing of <body> tag? Could you take a look at [this](http://www.jongales.com/blog/2011/01/10/google-analytics-and-jquery-mobile/) and [this](http://firedevcom.tumblr.com/post/22707422745/google-analytics-for-jquery-mobile)?

Comment: It seems to be the solution for both multipage templates (one html file with #'s) and single page templates (separate html files), isn't it? If it so, I really like that, but have few more questions. Is it all I need, or do I need to include code from google as well? It seems to me, that I should paste it instead of   '_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);' from google code, am I right? I need to use multidomain code with 'setDomainName' and 'setAllowLinker'.

Comment: And harder question. On one of my sites I actually use #'s as anchors with [this code](http://agilepro.com/mod_geek/javascript/jquery-mobile-internal-hash-links/). How should I modify your code for that site (to not track #'s as pageview)?

Comment: First, you STILL need to include the default Google Analytics code directly after you opening `<body>` tag as you usually would, with your multidomain variables and whatever else from Google. Then, the code in my updated answer would go in your `script.js` file. The ONLY thing you should need to modify in my Updated answer above is inserting your GA Account # in the `UA-XXXXXXX-X`. Everything else will pull from the original Google Analytics code. As for the script you're using with the `#` in the URL, that's over my head with the 5 min left before I leave work... but this should help.

Comment: Thank you. It's working for me. I found [Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) and your code just works with # anchors :)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Maybe you can consider replacing the depreciated [live](https://api.jquery.com/live/) method with [on](https://api.jquery.com/on/).